# foreach of queryselector runs 2 times and synatx for applying top and left position to each element from *ngFor(Angular7)

Tags: angular

I have some HTML content which I am assigning to a div and iterating over and to get a value in an *ngfor.

I have an issue in iterating. The foreach of queryselector iterates 2 times or more and the correct syntax to assign left and top positions to each element.

```js
droppeditem: string[]=[];
floor.droppeditem = this.droppeditem;
const floorImagePlanConatiner = document.createElement("div");

floorImagePlanConatiner.innerHTML = floor.image;

floorImagePlanConatiner.querySelectorAll('div div')
    .forEach(div => {
        floor.droppeditem = [];
        floor.droppeditem.push(div.textContent);
        div.querySelectorAll('span').forEach(span => {
            floor.droppeditem.push(span.textContent);
        });
        console.log(floor.droppeditem)
    });


Also here in ts code the issue is the div.textcontent gets all the 3 values(of div and of both spans ) but span.textcontent gets there respective values
```

The HTML:

```html
<div class="box"
     *ngFor="let existingZone of floor.droppeditem"
     [style.left.px]=""
     [style.top.px]="">
     {{ existingZone }}
</div>
```

The content which I am getting from backend and only purpose is to get the desired values using the above ts code in which I am creating a div and using queryselector to parse through:

The response

```
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" _ngcontent-c6="" appdropzone="" 
    appmovablearea="" class="dropzone" id="toget" ng-reflect-ng-style=" 
    [object Object]" style="width: 100%;
    background-image: url(&quot;data:image/jpeg;base64,/9//2Q==&quot;);
    background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center; 
    background-size: 100% 100%; border: 1px solid black; height: 340px;">

    <!--bindings={
    "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": " 502 "
    }-->

    <div _ngcontent-c6="" appmovable="" class="box draggable movable ng-star-inserted" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" touch-action="none" style="transform: translateX(196%) translateY(109.6%);">
        502
        <span _ngcontent-c6="" style="display: none">-196.00003051757812</span>
        <span _ngcontent-c6="" style="display: none">-109.5999755859375</span>
    </div>

    <!--bindings={
    "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": ""
    }-->

    <div _ngcontent-c6="" appmovable="" class="box draggable movable ng-star- inserted" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" touch-action="none" style="transform: translateX(196%) translateY(109.6%);">
        1002
        <span _ngcontent-c6="" style="display: none">-164.00003812</span>
        <span _ngcontent-c6="" style="display: none">-12.5999755859375</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to use above response which I get, its divs textcontent,values out of each span and passing it to each element being iterated over under the section html code . So I need to display 502 of each of the divs and apply their respective span values in top and left properties to each of the *ngFor divs.

Comment: Direct DOM manipulation is an anti-pattern in Angular.

Comment: @AndrewHill fine but it would be great if u help in some way, and I am only getting values and assigning it, I am not doing dom manipulation thehtml code which i have pasted at last(I am not rendering in the view , that is a backendresponse which I get) that I am iterating and getting the values only  which is not displayed in the dom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is: you want to get (**scrape**) values from the html file. I have created the sample Angular app. please take a look. I have changed the output to [Object Array]

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xoubeu

Thanks!
Sachin K

Comment: This looks cool , thanks, but how can I assign values from that , please suggest.

Comment: simple use `[style.left.px]="existingZone.spans[0]"`  + updated on https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xoubeu

Comment: Thanks alot , can I also provide this left and top within ngstyles and instead of px can I also use em as I want to make it responsive wrt to its parent and one last thing the position property as well , the syntax, I'll accept the answer :)

Comment: `[ngStyle]="{'top.px': existingZone.spans[0]}"`

Comment: Thanks a lot I will accept , I have one more issue if you could have a look please, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57482623/the-x-and-y-values-retrieved-get-applied-to-all-ngfor-elements

Comment: Hey Sachin I was trying to make the span text which is number in negative to a +ve one using =  Math.abs(parseInt(span.textContent.trim())) but it rounds of where as I want the exact number but in +ve

Comment: replace `parseInt` with `parseFloat`

Comment: Oh my bad in a hurry forgetting the basics, could you please suggest for this issue as well, thanks,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57482623/the-x-and-y-values-retrieved-get-applied-to-all-ngfor-elements

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197944/discussion-between-enthu-and-sachink).