# The mousemove event throws error in angular

Tags: angular, dom-events

I am trying to calculate the top and left of *ngfor elements wrt to parent element
The mousemove function throws me an error.

I tried referencing the parent element to capture the mousemove

```js
private elem;
private container;
private mouse = {
  x: null,
  y: null,
  down: false
};
private will_draw = false;

@ViewChild('parentcontainer') flo;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.elem = this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('box');
  this.container = this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('dropzone');
}

@HostListener('mousedown', ['$event'])
onMousedown(event) {
  this.mouse.down = true;
}

@HostListener('mouseup', ['$event'])
onMouseup(event) {
  this.mouse.down = false;
}

@HostListener('flo:mousemove', ['$event'])
documentMouseMove(e: MouseEvent) {
  // move logic
  if (!this.mouse.down) { return; }

  const container_rect = this.container.getBoundingClientRect();
  // relative to container, in px
  this.mouse.x = e.clientX - container_rect.left;
  this.mouse.y = e.clientY - container_rect.top;
  if (!this.will_draw) {
    requestAnimationFrame(this.draw);
    this.will_draw = true;
  }

}

draw() {
  this.will_draw = false;
  const { width, height } = this.container.getBoundingClientRect();
  const perc_x = this.mouse.x / width * 100;
  const perc_y = this.mouse.y / height * 100;
  // -5 to center (elem has its width set to 10%)
  console.log('left', (perc_x - 5) + '%');
  // -5 to center (elem has its height set to 10%)
  console.log('top', (perc_y - 5) + '%');
}
```

HTML:

```html
<div id="toget"
     #parentcontainer
     class="dropzone">
  <div class="box"
       appMovable
       *ngFor="let existingZone of existingDroppedItemZoneIn">
    {{ existingZone }}
    <span>{{leftvalue}}</span>
    <span>{{topvalue}}</span>
  </div>

  <div class="box"
       #bo
       *ngFor="let box of dropzone1"
       appDroppable
       (dragStart)="currentBox = box"
       appMovable>
    {{ box.dis }}
    <span>{{leftvalue}}</span>
    <span>{{topvalue}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The objective is to trigger mousemove event and calculate top and left value of ngfor elements
To listen to mouseup, mousedown , mousemove

[image]

Comment: @Flix, I had reffered this and I am using viewchild but its not helping , and also the ngfor elements will be dragged and dropped , then I need to calculate top and left

Comment: Please copy and paste the error message as text, not as an image of text. Search engines cannot index the error message when it is in an image, and it makes it harder for people to read.

Comment: The error message:  ERROR Error: Unsupported event target null for event mousemove

Comment: The error is not ViewChild, the error is that the HostListener on `documentMouseMove` is not supported in that way. The string `flo:mousemove` is not valid. The only valid values are `document:mousemove`, `window:mousemove`, `body:mousemove` or `mousemove`.

Comment: @Flix So how can I capture mousemove event , I had referred earlier before posting this question for the post u mentioned but not able to resolve it , if u could give any solution it would be really helpfull, thanks, the ngfor comes into play once the elements are dragged and dropped

Comment: Use a custom directive, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45722144/10207459).

Comment: @Flix any other way other than custom directive , what if I mention the event as( we do click) for mousemove, is that a valid one, and instead of writing a directive I cannot access it directly within that component

Comment: Yeah of course, you can do that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197989/discussion-between-enthu-and-flix).

Comment: @Flix, thakyou very much the above issue is resolved ur suggestion helped me, can you please help me out with this issue , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57482623/the-x-and-y-values-retrieved-get-applied-to-all-ngfor-elements